# Eclipse is not starting

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

Eclipse starts from terminal but when i try to start it from gui then it says java runtime environment don't found.

Environment variables are:

JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk1.6.0_20"
PATH=$PATH:"/opt/jdk1.6.0_20/bin"

And one more thing so far i normally copy jre folder from jdk to eclipse directory, which works fine but what is actual way. i mean this won't be standard way to do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit eclipse.ini (from the Eclipse folder) and add the following at the beginning:

```
-vm
C:/Java/jdk1.6.0_22/bin
```

where C:/Java/jdk1.6.0_22/bin should be your path to the java bin directory.
Keep it on two lines.

Comment: thanks xtian that worked and added -vm /opt/jdk1.6.0_20/bin in eclipse.ini

Answer (score 2):

> And one more thing so far i normally
>   copy jre folder from jdk to eclipse
>   directory, which works fine

No, this is not necessary or desirable.  You should not have to do any such thing.

If you open up a command shell and type "java -version", what comes back?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Well the reason eclipse won't start from GUI despite of the fact that environment variables are set, is:

You have set the variable in bashrc or bash_profile, these two are for the specific logged in user, but you also need to set in etc/profile which is for all the users.

So once you set the PATH and JAVA_HOME in etc/profile it will launch from GUI.

Worked for me! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem and the suggestion addressed my problem!
After setting /etc/profile as indicated in the link below, I logged out and logged back in for GUI based Eclipse to work.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/