# Eclipse doesn't open in Ubuntu after I updated Java plugin for Firefox

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, java

Recently I was facing problem in attending webex meeting with Firefox browser, so I visited Java documentation for updating Java plugin for Firefox at http://www.java.com/en/download/help/firefox_java.xml.
I did what was explained in there I got it working.

But after a couple of days when I tried starting my Eclipse, it didn't start. I got a small window like this --

[image]

I tried searching about it & understood, its related to $PATH but I don't know how to fix it as I don't have access to the GUI of Eclipse, so can't change the path. There must be some other way to do it.. I don't have expertise with IDE, so I need help on this..

**Edited:**

I visited the linked question & found I can solve it by editing eclipse.ini file. I did open it for edit and added the path, now it looks like --

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
```

You can see my added two lines just after 'openfile', which is --

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/java
```

I restarted the system & tried opening the eclipse, but same window comes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse cannot find Java on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774744/eclipse-cannot-find-java-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @mrt I couldn't solve my issue with the solution provided there about updating eclipse.ini file. Let me edit the question..

Comment: Try this: Open `/etc/environment` in any editor and add `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/java"`

Comment: I did that. Now it comes "A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/java".

Though this file is there..

Comment: Oh well, I solved it by updating the path which has been suggested in the 4th answer by Jeshurun. So I put 'JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so"' & it worked..

Comment: @mrt Can you please answer this question ?

Comment: You mean you set `JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so`, right? Or you really set `JAVA_HOME` to the path of the shared object file?

Comment: @mrt I set JAVA_HOME at /etc/environment

Comment: Are you sure when you are going to this path `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/java` you are having bin directory.?