# Eclipse is unable to find JVM in Ubuntu 12

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ubuntu, jvm

When I open eclipse in Ubuntu it is showing the following error:

```
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/opt/eclipse/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH
```

These are the Environment variables I set in .bashrc file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

I have also checked in terminal:

```
asr@asr-desktop:~$ java -version

java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)

asr@asr-desktop:~$ which java

/opt/jdk1.7.0/bin/java

asr@asr-desktop:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME

/opt/jdk1.7.0

asr@asr-desktop:~$ echo $PATH

/opt/softwares/apache-ant-1.7.1/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/vidyayugpc/bin:/opt/jdk1.7.0/bin:/home/vidyayugpc/bin:/opt/jdk1.7.0/bin
```

The eclipse is opening via command prompt only, I have tried to specify JVM location in eclipse.ini file by adding the below line

-vm

/opt/jdk1.7.0/bin/java

But its not running again showing the same error jvm is not found.Can any one help me here?

Comment: use `-vm /opt/jdk1.7.0/bin` in the eclipse.ini and it should work.

Comment: I have given as you said in eclipse.ini but same problem again

Comment: I encountered the same problem, when i try to launch eclipse from GUI but it works when i launch eclipse from terminal.

Comment: @Sivakumar have you resolved it?

Comment: @ASR No, looking for solution.

Comment: Following link might solve your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876559/eclipse-is-not-starting

Comment: I tried that also but not working? is it problem with eclipse version or java version?

Comment: @ASR Did you tried in the following way `-vm` `/opt/jdk1.7.0/bin` in separate line. As suggested in the link i provided in the previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the Environment variables in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d/` and reboot.

Comment: Thanks finally i copied the environment variables in /etc/profile

Answer (score 2):

This work for me edit the **eclipse.ini** using any text editor and change your **-vm** path to real path of your JDK

```
-vm /opt/jdk1.6.0/bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly, your path seems fine

If you set up the -vm parameter you have to point to the bin folder, please try this:

```
-vm /opt/jdk1.7.0/bin/
```

Comment: If i start the eclipse from terminal it is working, without modifying eclipse.ini and strating eclipse from terminal is there any ways to set environment varaibles

Comment: Did you recognized, that when you start eclipse that eclipse is searching a JRE at a complete other location: /opt/eclipse/jre/bin/java, did the path changed after you -vm changes?